# Pydantic prevent conversion of incorrect type

Tags: python-3.x, pydantic

Pydantic appears to perform automatic type conversion when the type of a property is not what is expected. I believe this is why (conveniently) it is possible to assign the value of an int enum property of a class via its raw int value.

However I have a scenario where I want to avoid this behaviour and instead receive a validation error if a property is not of the expected type. See the following example:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import List

class Common(BaseModel):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        print(f"created {self.__class__.__name__} with {kwargs}")

class Child(Common):
    child_prop: int = None

class Parent(Common):
    child: Child

class Imposter(Common):
    imposter_prop: int

parent = Parent(
    child=Imposter(imposter_prop=0)
)
print(f"is child: {isinstance(parent.child, Child)}")
```

Output from executing this module:

```
created Imposter with {'imposter_prop': 0}
created Child with {'imposter_prop': 0}
created Parent with {'child': Imposter(imposter_prop=0)}
is child: True
```

As you can see Pydantic happily allows me to create a `Parent` with an `Imposter` object for the property that should be `Child`. It supports this by creating a `Child` using the properties of the `Imposter`. I don't want this to happen.

I've looked through the Pydantic docs but none of the configuration options are jumping out at me as candidates to change this behaviour. Is there anything I can do to prevent this attempted type conversion?

Answer (score 4):

If you were using something with builtin types and wanted to prevent coercion, you could utilize pydantic [strict types](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#strict-types). Given you are custom types, I believe you may need to explicitly define your own `validate(cls, v) @classmethod` etc in your custom types. They provide an [example](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#custom-data-types) for custom data type validation, including usage of `isinstance` that you will want to utilize.